# Read the first line in a stream and remove it from the stream

Tags: java

I have 2 classes who must read an `InputStream`, the first one should only interpret the first line of the stream BUT the first line should be removed from the stream so that class B can interpret everything after the first line. Which doesn't work when I pass my `InputStream` to a `BufferedReader` and do a `readLine()`.

I know I could do a read on the stream until I've encountered a \b but maybe a more proper solution exists to do the job?

```
// Reads the first line from the stream and everything else
public String retrieveFileNameFromTheFirstLineInInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
    return reader.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't **remove** something from an `InputStream`, you just can **read** from it. Don't use the `BufferedReader` to read the line, because it surely will read much more than the first line from the `InputStreamReader` (to fill its buffer) which itself reads from the `InputStream`.

I'd suggest to read using the `InputStreamReader` until the end of the line is reached, then pass the `InputStream` instance to your code which should read it.

BTW, you always should specify the encoding used by the `InputStreamReader`, otherwise the system encoding will be used to convert the bytes from the `InputStream` to characters which can differ on different machines.

Comment: I've edited my question, there was an fault in my unit test but indeed the reader reads everything. What's the advantage of using an InputStreamReader iso the InputStream itself?

Comment: It appears to me from trying this code that even InputStreamReader can buffer input, so passing the InputStream after it's been used will miss whatever the first InputStreamReader buffered.

Answer (score 4):

I believe even InputStreamReader can buffer input, so Mike L's answer can miss input.

It's awkward, but you could use [ReaderInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReaderInputStream.html) from Apache commons-io.  So:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(in));
String firstLine = reader.readLine();
InputStream in2 = new ReaderInputStream(reader);
// continue with in2 ..
```